# get value of an item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I have a `td`:

```
<td id="divInTimeStamp-5-2" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red;">
    12:55 PM 
    <span><img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="/Content/themes/base/images/info.png"><span class="tooltip">Clocked in from: <br>Host: id14011.o2.local<br>IP Address: 10.0.2.49</span></span> 
    <a title="Edit ClockIn Time" class="inline UpdateLink timeSheetIdentity" href="">[ Δ ]</a>
</td>
```

How can I get the value 12:55 PM from the `td`?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = $.trim($('#divInTimeStamp-5-2')[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gXhsu/)

- `[0]` gets a reference to the DOM element `#divInTimeStamp-5-2`. It is a shorthand for [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild) gets its first child text node.
- [`.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue) contains the text node's content.
- [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) for cross-browser white space trimming.

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
var value = $('#divInTimeStamp-5-2').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).text()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LrzN7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cloned = $('#divInTimeStamp-5-2').clone();
cloned.find('*').remove();
var time = cloned.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

If time format is always `[HH:MM PM (8 chars)`]:

```
$('#divInTimeStamp-5-2').text().substring(0,9);
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tfkqe/1/)